# PHP mysql cannot insert data

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

```
// Do not put any echo code other than the last line.

// didnt include $con in the post.
    $userlvlid            = $_POST["userlvlid"]; 
    $username             = $_POST["username"];
    $password             = $_POST["password"];
    $lname                = $_POST["lname"];
    $fname                = $_POST["fname"];
    $mname                = $_POST["mname"];
    $birthdate            = $_POST["birthdate"];
    $streename            = $_POST["streetname"];
    $province             = $_POST["province"];
    $city                 = $_POST["city"];
    $barangay             = $_POST["barangay"];

    $organization_name    = $_POST["orgname"];
    $email_address        = $_POST["email_address"];
    $license              = $_POST["license"];


    if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else{
      // means connection successful.
     echo "sucess";
    }


    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'  ";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // means username already exists.
    }

    else {
           $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (`userlvlid`,
                                  `username`,
                                  `password`,
                                  `lname`,
                                  `fname`,
                                  `mname`,
                                  `birthdate`,
                                  `streetname`,
                                  `region`,
                                  `province`,
                                  `city`,
                                  `barangay`,
                                  `orgname`,
                                  `email`,
                                  `license`)

               VALUES  
                                   ('$userlvlid',
                                    '$username',
                                    '$password',
                                    '$lname',
                                    '$fname',
                                    '$mname',
                                    '$birthdate'
                                    '$streetname', 
                                    '$region',
                                    '$province',
                                    '$city',
                                    '$barangay',
                                    '$organization_name',
                                    '$email_address',
                                    '$license')";


        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

        $response["success"] = true;  
           } 

           else {

           }       


        }


        }

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Can someone explain  why "mysqli_query($con, $sql)" is returning false? I can't find what is wrong in the code. my database contains all of the fields and here maybe a syntax error. The code doesn't give me any errors and it doesn't add the information to the database.

Comment: Have you tried something like `mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con))` ?

Comment: Check your columns if its datatype match to your value

Comment: Can you provode your table structure.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Also if an not null column is leave it can also be a cause

Comment: print the query and run the query in phpmyadmin and see whats happening

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: slr, yea i saw the error. my bad thank you btw.

Answer (score 1):

A few things, first this part is not needed:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'  ";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // means username already exists.
}
```

Why? Because in between the time that you check for the user's existence and the time that you insert a new record, another client may create a user with the same username. So your second query the insert will fail if it happens (provided of course that you have a unique index on your username as you should).

Secondly, you are not escaping parameters. This leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. And it could also lead to malformed queries that do not get executed correctly - result data is not inserted. Use prepared statements instead.

```
$sql = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO accounts (`userlvlid`,
                              `username`,
                              `password`,
                              `lname`,
                              `fname`,
                              `mname`,
                              `birthdate`,
                              `streetname`,
                              `region`,
                              `province`,
                              `city`,
                              `barangay`,
                              `orgname`,
                              `email`,
                              `license`)

           VALUES  
                               (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?...)";
```

Then you need to bind the params

```
mysqli_bind_params($stmt,('$userlvlid',"ssssssssssssss",
                                $userlvlid
                                $username,
                                $password,
                                $lname,
                                $fname,
                                $mname,
                                $birthdate,
                                $streetname, 
                                $region,
                                $province,
                                $city,
                                $barangay,
                                $organization_name,
                                $email_address,
                                $license));
```

Ugly isn't it? That's why one should use `PDO` instead of `mysqli` but using mysqli without prepared statements is just horrible so we have to slog through this.

Now while going through this copy paste, I discovered the real cause of your problem

```
                                '$mname',
                                '$birthdate' /*** no comma here ***/
                                '$streetname',
```

Comment: you mentioned here that i do not need this part? $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'  ";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // means username already exists.
}               any other solution so I can validate for unique usernames?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, a unique index will prevent the same username being reused. A select followed by an insert is not a substitute for  a unique index. Search for database race conditions

Comment: i do have an id that auto-increments every time a user registers but I still dont get how a unique index can prevent the same username from being used

Comment: Well it's by definition. May I suggest that you read up on it? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: You are most welcome. Since you are still new here, may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Try using echo for the `$sql` and place the exit after that statement. So that it breaks the query execution after that.

By doing this you can find whether any error is available in the query and you can rectify it.

> Note: You first put echo to the Insert Statement and then break the execution by putting the exit; and you copy the statement that is echoed and place it in SQL of the DB and then check whether any error occurs in insertion. If no error occurs remove the echo and delete the exit;

If you have any Table Column mismatch or and Data Discrepancy you can rectify with the help of this echoed query.

Ensure that you provide values that are matching the values that are given into the DB.

> **Note: **(E.g) if `userlvlid` - varchar(11) - You should provide value which is equal to 11 or less than 11 if you enter the value greater than 11 it will not be inserting and the query will fail from there on.